# Setting a jump counter in my 2d platformer built with phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser, jumping

I have a platforming game, written in javascript with the Phaser.js framework, where my character collects objects. I thought trying to collect all objects in the least amount of jumps would be interesting, so I tried to implement a jump counter. Relevant pieces of code:

```
var jumpCount = 0;
var jumpText;

function create (){
    jumpText = this.add.text(16, 48, 'Jumps Used: 0', {fontsize: '32px', fill: '#000'});
}

function update (jumpCount){
    if (cursors.space.isDown && player.body.touching.down){
        player.setVelocityY(-630);
        jumpCount++;
        jumpText.setText('Jumps Used: ' + jumpCount);
    }
}
```

This is displaying the counter and incrementing it *sort of* correctly, but it seems to count the amount of time that the spacebar is held down and is leading to jump counts that are floats well into the thousands.

Is there a more reasonable way to handle counting the number of times a player has manually jumped?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking in the `update` you can instead add a binding to the key itself. In Phaser 2, which it looks like you might be using:

```
jumpButton = this.game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR);
jumpButton.onDown.add(jump, this);

function jump() {
    // Add your existing logic here.
}
```